# Migrate Firefox profile to a new one

Tags: firefox, crash

I reinstalled Firefox, because my profile was crashing. I backed up my `~/.mozilla` folder to some other place, uninstalled firefox and installed it again.
New firefox wasn't crashing. So I copied one of my backup up old profile to new firefox, and that profile was crashing again.

Now, I would like to use completely fresh profile and copy only the things that I need from the old profile that is crashing. Which files need I to replace? I need bookmarks (the quick access bar with bookmarks is sufficient for me and I need all the extensions with extension data). What could I also need and forget?
I want to try it, I will at least find out, if it is some extension that's causing the crashes. But, I think it is not. It starts usually when I open a new tab and the page won't load.

My OS is `Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`. Firefox version is `112.0.2 32 bit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall firefox if the system files are not corrupted or damaged.

**Firefox Safe Mode**

You can also start firefox in the `safe mode`, so the extensions are disabled

[How to Start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://www.wikihow.com/Start-Firefox-in-Safe-Mode)

> Firefox Safe Mode is a troubleshooting mode that temporarily disables all extensions, themes, and custom settings in Firefox and starts the browser with default settings. It is designed to help you diagnose and fix problems with Firefox, such as performance issues, crashes, or problems with add-ons.

**Firefox profiles with `firefox -p`**

You can start your firefox with `firefox -p`

Now you get a new popup window where you can create, delete or rename  profiles for firefox

Just unmark `Use the selected profile without asking at startup`

and after that every time firefox start's you can select the profile you wanna work with

You can create different profiles for different use-cases

On my debian gnu/linux the config files are in

`~/.mozilla/firefox/`

You can copy or backup the profiles from there

The starts with `varchar+name` like `5v96ky6z.AI` but you can rename them and you can copy and start them from an other disk, usb, sshfs/fuse, samba share, nfs, etc..

If you rename and move the folder you need to edit the `profiles.ini`, in my case the `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`

You have different blocks for each profile that looks like this:

```
[Profile0]
Name=MENU_NAME
IsRelative=0
Path=/home/USER/FOLDER_NAME
Default=1
```

`Default=1` You only have this once in the file for only one profile, you can delete this it is not absolutely necessary

`Default` is the standard profile that will start if
`Use the selected profile without asking at startup` is selected

`Name=MENU_NAME` The name for your selected profile in the menu list

`Path=/home/USER/FOLDER_NAME` The path and the folder name of your profile

You can use a relative or an absolute path, you can use `IsRelative=0`
`IsRelative=1`

```
[Profile1]
Name=USERNAME2
IsRelative=0
Path=/MYPATH/FOX2
```

The name of the selected user `Name=USERNAME2` and the name of the folder `Path=/MYPATH/FOX2` do not have to be the same

You can add or delete you profiles entries from the backup
Don't forget the enumeration of the number must always take place in the order
`[Profile0], [Profile1], [Profile2]`

but in the file the arrangement can be messed up not in the order
`[Profile2], [Profile0], [Profile1]`

You can't have `[Profile0], [Profile1]` and `[Profile3]` without and existing
dummy-entry or profile named `[Profile2]`

If you start firefox and the menu is empty, you may have a syntax error.

**Backup profile files:**

This are the files i do my backup logins, bookmarks, without the extensions or others..

- `places.sqlite`
- `logins.json`
- `logins-backup.json`
- `key4.db`

or you backup the whole profile folder, in my case for profile `5v96ky6z.AI` `~/.mozilla/firefox/5v96ky6z.AI`

`places.sqlite` is the storage for the bookmarks

For the quick access bar with bookmarks, for your session search for
the folders `sessionstore` or `sessionstore-backups` or the files `sessionstore.jsonlz4`

**Firefox Sync**

You can also link your firefox profile to an email and thus synchronize everything between different firefox instances or computers.

[Sync your Firefox on any device](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/)

[How do I set up Sync on my computer?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer)

**Addons & Extensions|xpi(Cross-Platform Install) package/file:**

In the profile path `~/.mozilla/firefox/5v96ky6z.AI/extensions` in the folder `extensions` there are the `{--ID--}.xpi` packages, every addon is a `{--ID--}.xpi` with an `ID`

you can open a package with double click an you can see all the files that belongs to an addon example: `{b9acf540-acba-11e1-8ccb-001fd0e08bd4}.xpi`

In the `manifest.json` file you get all the information about that selected addon, like description, version. etc.

You can copy this addon to your new/selected profile by right mouse click `open as` than select firefox start the profile you wanna install to or select `open file` from your `firefox menu` and you can easy install that addon from this package

You can also see the extensions if you start `about:config` in firefox as url and search for

`extensions.webextensions.ExtensionStorageIDB.migrated.`

If you start `about:support` scroll down and you will find in the `Add-ons` area the Addon name for the `{--ID--}.xpi` package `ID`

There are also 3 files in the profile path `~/.mozilla/firefox/5v96ky6z.AI/` where you can find other information about the search-engines, settings, etc..:

- `extension-preferences.json`
- `extensions.json`
- `prefs.js`

Maybe you need the `addonStartup.json.lz4` file, I did not backup that.

In the `storage` directory you will find a subfolder for each installed add-on but some add-ons, maybe store the data in a different location/directory in your profile path

**What else:**

- Check if there is an addon for your firefox version available
  to export/backup your addons

**Backup with terminal and bash:**

You can write a bash script to backup all the files you need, with `cp` or `rsync` and/ or create a `tar` file

**Write your on `addon|xpi(Cross-Platform Install)`:**

[Your first extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)

[Your second extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension)

How do I create an addon for Firefox?

> Open the `about:debugging` page, click the This Firefox option, click the Load Temporary Add-on button, then select any file in your extension's directory. The extension now installs, and remains installed until you restart Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. You forgot only, how to safely copy extensions from one profile to another?

Comment: @xralf | i will be back later than i will add more information... max 1 hour ^^

Comment: So, it's not possible to simply copy the extensions from command-line? I'm using i3 window manager, which file manager you suggest to use when it is not possible do it command line?

Comment: And another thing. I'd like to copy the data associated with the extensions as well. For example I'm using Element Blocker, SiteDelta watch, Adblock Plus and they have some data associated with them and I'd like to transfer them to new profile as well.

Comment: You can copy all files you need from the terminal, i use a bash script with cp or rsync for my ff backup

Comment: I will Check your other question in the comments tomorrow gn ;)

Comment: Thank you. And by `the quick access bar with bookmarks` I meant `pinned tabs`. It's also in the file `places.sqlite`?

Comment: [This](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox) could be useful. I managed to transfer `pinned tabs` as well.